# Other options than using engine "openpyxl" in python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, writer

Currently I'm using the engine "openpyxl" in Python to replacing data in excel.
It cost me almost 54 min to go through 250k lines. Are there other engine options?

I tried to use xlsxwriter but I my code I need to use mode'a' as well, what is not allowed in xlswriter.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(new_file,  mode='a',engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', startrow=0, startcol=0)
```

Comment: Calamine maybe?

Comment: Hi @sammywemmy, how should I use Calamine if I compare what I have written as openpyxl code?

Comment: _It cost me almost 54 min to go through 250k lines._  well. from information provided it is not clear where the actual bottleneck is... What makes you think it's the writing to excel? 250K lines is not that much at all when it comes to writing

Comment: To explain it correct. I've a excel file (A) with data and some tabs with pivots. We would like to maintain the pivots so we can play around. What I need is collect the data from on other excel source (2 milions lines), filtering and copy the data into my excel A on a certain tab. From there I can use the data and can manual change the pivots. Filtering cost me 1 second and the result is 250k lines with 16 colums. So the last step, copying cost me 54 minutes.